Tensorflow-data-validation installing issue
I'm using Python 3.12, and I'm trying to install the latest version (1.15.1) of TensorFlow Data Validation. However, while installing, I encountered the following error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-data-validation (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-data-validation

The tensorflow official page mention that Python version requirerement is >3.9, which is met in my environment. How can I resolve this issue?
My environment is as follows:

Python - 3.12
Pip - 24.1
tensorflow - 2.16.0rc0
setuptools - 72.1.0
numpy -1.26.4


Looking at https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-data-validation/, it Python 3.12 may be a bit far ahead. The latest supported version may be 3.11. See a 2018 question in which Python 3 was not yet supported.

TensorFlow Data Validation is not officially supported on Python 3.12. It is compatible with python versions 3.9 to 3.11. To install tensorflow-data-validation==1.15.1, consider using Python 3.10 or Python 3.11. Check this document for compatible python versions.
